# Show that this vector space spans V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Im unsure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The inclusion $\langle v_1,\dots,v_{n-2}\rangle \subset \langle v_1,\dots,v_{n}\rangle$ is obvious.

To prove the reverse inclusion, you just have to prove that  $v_n\in \langle v_1,\dots,v_{n-2}\rangle$. (For $v_{n-1}$, this is by hypothesis).